# Versioning API urls using AWS code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, api-gateway

I have two cloudformation stacks, one creates API gateways(v1) as well as Lambdas and some other things like roles and policies. The other stack is a code piepeline template.

In addition, I have a AWS code pipeline stack that basically deploys the environment previously defined when changes occurs. It works great, It exposes methods like /v1/method1 and /v1/method1, but now I want to create version two of the methods but previous versions should be maintainable(I should be able to redeploy if they have issues).

```
Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
          Description: 
          Handler: 
          Runtime: python3.7
          CodeUri: 
          Tracing: Active
          Timeout: 300
          Role: !GetAtt 'LambdaExecRole.Arn'
          Events:
            ConnectionOptions:enter code here
              Type: Api
              Properties:
                #here is where I addd the sub
                Path: !Sub '/${version}/method1'
                Method: GET
```

According to this,  I wanted to add a new parameter in the pipeline which indicates the version that I want to deploy(e.g v2)

So in the "deploy" stage I planned to override the version in the previous stack(the one that created teh component first), but here is the problem....

I defined my Lambdas in cloudformation using SAM and SAM does not support "!Sub" operation. Is there any other alternative to manage versioning correctly?

Comment: 2 things - First, can you specify the exact error cloudformation throws at you? Second, if nothing works, try a templating solution like jinja, which would take in your CF template and replaces the variables before SAM processes it.

Comment: Finally, since I am going to maintain two versions only(current and latest stable) I will add two Lambdas and two Gateways in the template instead of parametrizing the path name. Thx.